# Convert Jupterlab ipynb to Executable

Tags: python, tkinter, executable, jupyter-lab

I have an .ipynb file developed in jupyterlab. This file only contains one cell. When I run the cell in juptyterlab it runs an application developed using Tkinter.

Is there any way to create a stand alone executable from this?

Answer (score 1):

I have made my Tkinter programs into executables using cx_freeze. You may have to copy the contents of the .ipynb into a .py file for it to work. Documentation below.

https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/